# onPress function with parameters runs creates loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I have this component that has a simple button, when i press the button a new Meta should be added to the display

Metas.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import Meta from './Meta';
import Button from './Button';

class Metas extends Component {
    componentWillMount() {
        this.setState({
            metas: this.props.data,
        });
    }

    addMeta = (newMeta) => {
        console.log('Adding new meta');
        /*this.props.navigator.push({
            id: 'Test'
        });*/
        const metas = this.state.metas;
        metas.push(newMeta);
        this.setState({ metas });
        console.log(`Metas: ${metas}`);
    }

    renderData = () => {
        console.log('rendering metas data');
        return this.state.metas.map(meta => <Meta key={Math.random()} name={meta} />);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                { this.renderData() }
                <View>
                    <Text>{this.state.metas.length} Metas</Text>
                    <Button
                        text='+'
                        color='#8783FF'
                        fontColor='white'
                        size='50'
                        fontSize='25'
                        onPress={this.addMeta('New Meta')}
                    />
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

export default Metas;
```

The paremeter of the function addMeta will be inserted by the user in the future but i am currently just testing how rerendering works

The problem is,if i pass no parameter through the function, and define a variable inside addMeta it works perfectly(did this to test if the method was binded), but if i do as displayed above, it runs the function in the onPress property without me even clicking it, resulting in a crash of my application

Button.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, TouchableNativeFeedback } from 'react-native';

class Button extends Component {
    render() {
        const { buttonStyle, centerHorizontally, textStyle } = styles;
        const { text, onButtonPress } = this.props;

        return (
            <TouchableNativeFeedback onPress={onButtonPress}>
                <View style={buttonStyle}>
                    <View style={centerHorizontally}>
                        <Text style={textStyle}>{text}</Text>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </TouchableNativeFeedback>
        );
    }
}

const styles = {
    buttonStyle: {
        borderRadius: 100,
        justifyContent: 'space-around',
        height: parseInt(this.props.size, 10),
        width: parseInt(this.props.size, 10),
        backgroundColor: this.props.color
    },
    /*TODO: use text align center instaed*/
    centerHorizontally: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'space-around'
    },
    textStyle: {
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        fontSize: parseInt(this.props.fontSize, 10),
        lineHeight: parseInt(this.props.fontSize, 10)
            + Math.floor(parseInt(this.props.fontSize, 10) / 10) + 1,
        color: this.props.fontColor
    }
};

export default Button;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see you are executing `addMeta` when rendering component. I don't know if it's intentional but it causes that the `New Meta` is added before you press the button.

Instead of executing the function like here:

```
onPress={this.addMeta('New Meta')}
```

Try something like this:

`onPress={() => {this.addMeta('New Meta')}}`

Comment: how is it executing addMeta? as it is a onPress property shouldnt it only run when i press it? And as a noob question why would ur suggestion work? On my view is calling a arrow funtion in another arrow function

Comment: `onPress={this.addMeta('New Meta')}` will invoke on every render. When you do `onPress={this.addMeta}`, it will only invoke the function when pressed, but since you want to pass a parameter, you can create an anonymous function that will be invoked only on press `onPress={() => this.addMeta('New Meta')}`

Answer (score 1):

You are ***invoking*** `this.addMeta` when you add braces to it:

```
<Button 
  text='+' color='#8783FF' 
  fontColor='white' size='50' 
  fontSize='25' 
  onPress={this.addMeta('New Meta')}
<!-- These braces -----^----------^        
      cause the function to execute         
-->
/>
```

**Solution:**

Remove braces and make sure you that when you call the passed down method of `addMeta` in your `<Button>` component, that you pass in the relevant argument at that point:

```
<Button 
  text='+' color='#8783FF' 
  fontColor='white' size='50' 
  fontSize='25' 
  onPress={this.addMeta.bind(this)}
  <!--
    ensure you bind this method to
     local component scope
     (You can do this in the constructor instead
     if here if you like)
  -->
/>
```

*Button.js*

```
class Button extends Component {
  handleOnPress(){
    this.props.onPress(parameterToPass);
  }

  render() {
    const {buttonStyle, centerHorizontally, textStyle } = styles; 
    const { text } = this.props; 

    return (
      <TouchableNativeFeedback 
          onPress={this.handleOnPress}> 
        <View style={buttonStyle}> 
          <View style={centerHorizontally}> 
            <Text style={textStyle}>{text}</Text> 
          </View> 
        </View> 
      </TouchableNativeFeedback> 
    ); 
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why but this should work;

```js
<Button
  text='+'
  color='#8783FF'
  fontColor='white'
  size='50'
  fontSize='25'
  onPress={this.addMeta.bind(null, 'New Meta')}
/>
```